# How to create Android Material Ghost button?

Tags: android, material-design

With new update of AppCompat v23.4.0, I consider 2 styles for Button:

- `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored`
- `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored`

And they look like this:

[image]

Also with ripple affect. But I want to create a ghost button that looked like UNINSTALL button of Play Store app with the ripple affect like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code for background xml:

rounded_corner_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#7FAE56"/>

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

</shape>
```

and set this as button background

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_background"/>
```

for Ripple effect, there are many libraries available..
Here is one example
https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

Comment: How do you get the ripple effect added to the click event of your shape?

Comment: Plz check my edited answer

Comment: I have done like you do but it has no Ripple effect. I don't want to use any library of ripple effect. I want to use from default system or from AppCompat if it's available, the click feedback of button.

Comment: You'll get default ripple effect above android 5.0 only. And you'll need just one class for ripple effect. If you don't want to use library, then you can just paste that class to your project..